# Adjective to qualify "struggle"

Tags: word-choice

> The ascent of Mount Everest was first conquered nearly sixty years ago, but it nevertheless remains a symbol of […] struggle in the popular psyche, demanding incredible determination and physical endurance.

What word should be used instead of […]?

1. arduous
2. daedalean
3. colossal
4. adamant
5. herculean
6. gordian

I selected the first and the fifth options because these two refer to physical hard work, but the answer is given as third and fifth. How can the third option be better than the first?

Comment: Sonia, are you asking in order to have an answer in reference to your choice #5 or in reference to the author's choice #3?

Comment: I think this is POB. Initially I would have ruled out *daedalean* and *gordian* (both effectively meaning *intricate, complex* in this context), but even they are in principle defensible. Only *adamant* seems like a complete no-hoper. Also, I'm somewhat distrustful of anyone who speaks of *conquering **the ascent** of Everest*, since nearly everyone else either just conquers the mountain itself, or some particular route to the summit.

Comment: It's a very slapdash piece of writing, both the question (as FumbleFingers points out) and the answers. The author clearly thinks that *colossal* means something like "great, impressive, tremendous", and it doesn't: it means "very large, gigantic", size terms which cannot properly be imputed to an action (*struggle*). I agree with you that *arduous* is a much better choice. Unhappily, you and I don't get a vote. +1 for the question.

Comment: Interestingly, *task* and *struggle* have been used [about equally over the past couple of centuries](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=task%2Cstruggle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But [*herculean struggle* is virtually unknown by comparison with *herculean task*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=herculean+task%2Cherculean+struggle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). I'm tempted to wonder if whoever set this question is even a native speaker of English.

Comment: Not only does this seem to be to be primarily opinion based, I'm struggling to see how either the OP or any future learner of English would be able to make use of any answer to this question to further their understanding of English. To that end, and given that four other people have also voted to close, I'm going to cast my vote to put the question on hold.

Comment: It seems to me that while *arduous* would apply better to the physical climbing of Mount Everest, *colossal* seems better for the context of the sentence. I say this because the sentence is talking about "**a symbol of** (blank) struggle in the popular psyche", for which I believe *colossal* is a better fit than *arduous*, which is better suited for a literal description of the climb rather than what it represents. Even this distinction is fairly subjective however, leading me to conclude that the the original question is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I would have selected 1 and 5 as well. (Note: I am not a native English speaker.)

A struggle (in the sense of an effort, rather than a fight) is usually described as difficult. It feels a bit strange to talk of a large struggle. Since *arduous* means very difficult, “arduous struggle” is a perfectly natural superlative: choice 1 is definitely correct.

“Herculean struggle” is also correct because “Herculean” can have two meanings: big and strong like [Hercules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules), or difficult and strenuous like his [labours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labours_of_Hercules) (tasks). One would usually say ”… remains a symbol of *a Herculean task*“ though.

*Colossal* means very large, so it feels unidiomatic to talk of a “colossal struggle” here, though I think the phrase would be understood without trouble.

[Statistics](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arduous+struggle%2Ccolossal+struggle%2Cherculean+struggle%2CHerculean+struggle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) show that “arduous struggle” is definitely idiomatic, and “Herculean struggle” and “colossal struggle” are markedly rarer. The [peak on “colossal struggle”](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colossal+struggle%2Cherculean+struggle%2CHerculean+struggle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) starting in 1914 seems to be due to descriptions of World War I, with *struggle* meaning a fight rather than an effort (justifying the description as large: it's a large fight because it involves a lot of people).